# Exibir resultado de tabela relacionada sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Bom gostaria da ajuda dos senhores, tenho duas tabelas cliente e produto
um cliente pode ter vários produtos e um produto pertence apenas a um cliente,
tenho um relacionamento usando o sequelize,
porem no log não consigo exibir o resultado da tabela relacionada, que chega para mim desta maneira

```
[ clientes {
dataValues: {
  id: 1,
  cliente: 'Mayk A  Bublitiz',
  email: 'reaperbr21@gmail.com',
  celular: 'sdasds',
  telefone: '984217583',
  comments: [Array]
},
_previousDataValues: {
  id: 1,
  cliente: 'Mayk A  Bublitiz',
  email: 'reaperbr21@gmail.com',
  celular: 'sdasds',
  telefone: '984217583',
  comments: [Array]
},
_changed: Set {},
_options: {
  isNewRecord: false,
  _schema: null,
  _schemaDelimiter: '',
  include: [Array],
  includeNames: [Array],
  includeMap: [Object],
  includeValidated: true,
  attributes: [Array],
  raw: true
},
isNewRecord: false,
comments: [ [pedidos], [pedidos], [pedidos] ]},clientes {
dataValues: {
  id: 2,
  cliente: 'Maydasdask A  Bublitiz',
  email: 'reaperbr21@gmail.com',
  celular: 'dasds',
  telefone: '984217583',
  comments: [Array]
},
_previousDataValues: {
  id: 2,
  cliente: 'Maydasdask A  Bublitiz',
  email: 'reaperbr21@gmail.com',
  celular: 'dasds',
  telefone: '984217583',
  comments: [Array]
},
_changed: Set {},
_options: {
  isNewRecord: false,
  _schema: null,
  _schemaDelimiter: '',
  include: [Array],
  includeNames: [Array],
  includeMap: [Object],
  includeValidated: true,
  attributes: [Array],
  raw: true
},
isNewRecord: false,
comments: [ [pedidos], [pedidos], [pedidos] ]},clientes {
dataValues: {
  id: 3,
  cliente: 'alone',
  email: 'reaperbr21@gmail.com',
  celular: 'adsd',
  telefone: '984217583',
  comments: [Array]
},
_previousDataValues: {
  id: 3,
  cliente: 'alone',
  email: 'reaperbr21@gmail.com',
  celular: 'adsd',
  telefone: '984217583',
  comments: [Array]
},
_changed: Set {},
_options: {
  isNewRecord: false,
  _schema: null,
  _schemaDelimiter: '',
  include: [Array],
  includeNames: [Array],
  includeMap: [Object],
  includeValidated: true,
  attributes: [Array],
  raw: true
},
isNewRecord: false,
comments: [ [pedidos], [pedidos], [pedidos] ]}]
```

meu relacionamento

```
db.Clientes.hasMany(db.Pedidos, { as: "comments" });db.Pedidos.belongsTo(db.Clientes, {foreignKey: "id_cliente",as: "tutorial",});
```

meeu codigo para exibir

```
  app.post('/pdf',urlencodeParser,function (req,res) {
Cliente.findAll({ include: [{model:Pedido, as:"comments" }]}).then(function (pagamentos) {
 console.log(typeof pagamentos);

 res.render('pdf',{teste2:pagamentos,layout:false})
})})
```

espero que os senhores possam me ajudar dês de já agradeço